# Parse XML (SRU) with php

Tags: php, xml

I have tried to parse an XML response that does not work. In the API docs it says that it is a XML based protocol: SRU. Wont this XML parsing code work then? Or is it some error in the code?

code:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('http://api.site.com/sru/query=' . $_GET['q']);
print_r($xmldoc);

$xpathvar = new Domxpath($xmldoc);
$queryResult = $xpathvar->query('//datafield[@tag="020"]/subfield[$code="a"]');
foreach ($queryResult as $result) {
    echo $result->textContent;
    print_r($result);
}
```

xml structure:

```
<searchRetrieveResponse>
    <numberOfRecords>1</numberOfRecords>
    <datafield tag="020" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
        <subfield code="a">xyz</subfield>
    </datafield>

    ...

</searchRetrieveResponse>
```

Comment: How do you know it "does not work"? Can you provide the error?

Comment: No output. And print_r($xmldoc) though shows that the xnl is fetched. Error should be afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign in `$code` (in the `xpathvar->query`) looks like it doesn't belong there. Try either removing or escaping the dollar sign, as appropriate in your case (removing looks appropriate, given the example xml).

Comment: I though this was only true for double quotes. Perhaps it is version-dependent?

Comment: No, you're correct... this is incorrect as it is now. I'm editing it now.

Comment: @eyekanal Sry my bad with the question posting. I edited the attribute for easier reading and put $ instead of @. The code has the correct syntax but is still not passing anything to $queryResults. The foreach loop does not go.